# Android UI, how to superpose fragment view?

Tags: android-fragments, android

I'm creating an Android application mobile. I'm starting a new one.

How can I implement the following:[image]

One foreground view that's don't use all the screen's space.

Thus I can have:

2 other background ListView. One is seen on top screen, and other at the foot screen.

I really need this for the transition between the foreground screen, and 2 other ListViews.

Comment: i dont know why but even that i saw your image i have no idea what you really need

Comment: Could You share Your current xml layout with two list views?

Comment: i only want have 1 foreground content, and 2 other listview background.

Then, with basic drag, we can display the top background listview, or foot background listview

Answer (score 0):

Look at some samples using http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html, given your picture that should be relatively simple :)